# How can I output a specific part of this multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

I have an array within an array that contains settings.  I need to figure out how to target specific parts of the array so i can turn them into a variable or output them.  Here is the array's vardump:

```
array(2)
{
 [0]=> object(stdClass)#101(1)
  {
    ["type"]=> string(9) "wordpress"
  }
 [1]=> object(stdClass)#122 (6)
  {
    ["type"]=> string(7) "divider" ["width"]=> string(4) "full" ["divider_type"]=> string(5) "solid" ["color"]=> string(0) "" ["padding_top"]=> string(0) "" ["padding_bottom"]=> string(0) ""
 }
}
```

I really don't know php that well.

Comment: Format your code into a readable fashion, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of objects.

Here is how you might access one of them.

```
echo $arr[0]->type;
```

Comment: I don't get it, why would you comment with the solution and then comment after that telling me to format my code?

Comment: @BRAINBUZZmedia: Because this is an answer, and the comment isn't. I see it as a general courtesy that if you come to this site for free help, please spend a few minutes ensuring your question is clear and easy to read.

Comment: What if I don't know what the output means and that is why I need help?

Comment: @BRAINBUZZmedia: Well where did the output come from? It looks like it is from `var_dump()`, which has line breaks and whitespace to make the output readable. In addition, it should be in a code block. Indent it by 4 spaces or a tab to make it a code block.

Comment: It came from a script a coder wrote for me and the var_dump gave me what I pasted as an output.  It was all in one line like that.

Comment: @BRAINBUZZmedia: Use your browser's *View Source* method on that output.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch a specific item from the array, you use the arrays keys. Let's assume you have an array called $foo and want to find the first value, use:

```
$first_value = $foo[0];
```

Your array contains objects, which in turn contains properties. To get a property value from an object, you user the property's name. Again, assume you have an object named $bar with a property named "count". You can access it like this:

```
$property_value = $bar->count.
```

Putting the two together, let's say you want the property "width" from the second object in your array, and let's assume your array is called $array. You access it like this:

```
$width = $array[1]->width;
```